# How can I display a calendar that can handle a lot of events?

Tags: calendar

I'm currently working on the UI and the UX of a calendar. Our company has a lot of events to deal with, and we need to display the calendar events on the month view, and also on a week and a day view.

I can't find good examples of calendar which handles a lot of events at the same time. Google agenda doesn't seem to handle it right. Is there a better way I can display such situations?

[image: Here's an example of a google calendar day for a day :]

Comment: Have you looked at Google Calendar, the OSX Calendar, Outlook, or other major examples? If they are not working for you, perhaps you could post some pictures of them and point out why they do not meet you UX needs.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some examples of sites that specializes in Events. You can go in and explore. I quite like the Meetup one.

http://www.meetup.com
This one summarizes all the events into a list split between "Today" "Tomorrow" or "This Week" or "This Month". It also lists out the events as opposed to full on calendar view. I believe this is a great practice as only current upcoming events are very relevant to users.

[image: meetup]

https://www.eventbrite.ca

[image: eventbrite]

facebook:
[image: facebook events]

Answer (score 2):

Since your screen real estate is physically setting the boarders for visibility, at some point you will not be able to read every event. My suggestion is to highlight the "density" of events through depth of color.

Blackberry [for example](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/blackberry-playbook-2-0-feature-breakdown-can-rim-save-its-forsaken-tablet/) increases font size of the days number with increasing number of events taking place on that day.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm auto answering myself, to present one solution that i've found by searching on dribbble :

- The site https://www.pittsburghglasscenter.org/calendar
- The dribbble : http://dribbble.com/shots/600945-Children-s-Museum-Responsive-Calendar

This solution allows to present multiple items per day by using a pager on each of these day.

Comment: Can you summarise what these solutions are, why they're suitable? This isn't a link aggregator site; it's a Question and Answer site so your answer should really stand alone as a useful answer in its own right.

Comment: that is a really nice calendar :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [Gantt Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart) would do the trick. Depending on your layout you have a lot of options regarding labels and amount of items. And it is rather common and intuitive as well.